How to solve a white spot at the 1980-09-12 day at a NetCDF4 dataset which prevents me to operate anything at CDO
After detrend a +13000 dataset, I cannot operate anything due to a bug at the 1980-09-12 day. It's only this one. In the attached photo you'll see the same day: at the right it's a print I took using ncview tools, at the left it's the SAME photo using the ncview too but with the normal viewer. enter image description here
As a big dataset, I could not use
cdo detrend infile outfile
I used
cdo trend infile afile bfile
and
cdo subtrend infile afile bfile outfile T
The documentation explains that detrend is equal to trend+subtrend and it's worked. But I always end up with this bug at only this 1980-09-12 day. Consequently, I cannot calculate EOFs or anything else. Would you have any idea on how to solve it?

It looks like the data for that day is nothing but missing values. You will need to either remove that day, fix the data somehow, or carry out temporal interpolation to provide values for that day
